# XPath: Select a node based on value of another node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

[I've looked at similar questions but none I found answer this, please do not mark a duplicate without actually reading it]

How would I select a node using the contents of `savetype` in xslt.

eg in this example `savetype=dexterity` so I want the value of

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/character/abilities/dexterity/bonus"/>
```

Is there anyway to do this without a `<xsl:choose>` statement, can I build the XPATH statement from the value of `savetype`

Sample file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root version="3.1" release="7|CoreRPG:3">
  <character>
     <abilities>
        <charisma>
           <bonus type="number">-1</bonus>
        </charisma>
        <constitution>
           <bonus type="number">2</bonus>
        </constitution>
        <dexterity>
           <bonus type="number">2</bonus>
        </dexterity>
     </abilities>
     <powers>
        <id-00005>
           <actions>
              <id-00001>
                 <savetype type="string">dexterity</savetype>
              </id-00001>
           </actions>
        </id-00005>
     </powers>
  </character>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I build the XPATH statement from the value of savetype

Yes. Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/character/abilities/*[name()=//savetype]/bonus" />
```

---

Another option is to use a key. Define a key at the top level of your stylesheet as:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="abilities/*" use="name()" />
```

then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('k', //savetype)/bonus" />
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `*` is for - almost looks like a pointer deference to me. I am guessing the part in `[]` is creating a node called whatever the value of savetype is. Also is `//` needed on savetype? Sorry - I'm new at xslt

Comment: @Adrian You are asking for an XPath tutorial, which I cannot provide in a comment. Briefly: `*` is wildcard that stands for any element, `[]` indicates a *predicate*, and in order to select the `savetype` element you need to provide a path to it - either a relative or an absolute one. Since the context is unknown, I have used an absolute one.